# I can't understand something about mat lab coding

Tags: matlab

generate a scatter-plot of log-normally distributed values of at
least 1000 random numbers in the interval [5;50] derived from a uniform distribution over the interval
[0;1].
I have done this so far

```
%declaring intervals
a=5;b=50;
%creating 1000 random number within the interval [5,50]
r = a + (b-a).*rand(1000,1);
```

I can not understand this part "**derived from a uniform distribution over the interval
[0;1].**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand` gives you a pseudorandom number between `0` and `1`. The probability of selecting any particular number form this interval is the same for any other number from the interval, hence the probability density function used by `rand` is called "uniformly distributed".

So, you started out fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I would take this to mean that you should map the range of numbers you want as output into the interval [0,1]. That is to say you partition the interval into 46 equally spaced subintervals, such that the intersection of each interval is empty and their union is [0,1]. Then to each subinterval, you associate a value of your output sample range then a sample from [0,1] lets you create a random sample from the set [5:50]

For example, if you wanted to create a sample from [1:10] you would choose generate a sample from uniform distribution on [0,1]. If the sample is in the interval [0,0.1) your output sample value is 1. If it was in the interval [0.2,0.3) your value would be 3 etc.

If your is asking what a uniform distribution actually is, it is simply a distribution where every point in the sample space has an equal probability of being chosen. See this for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29